# React-native handle login and signup

Tags: reactjs, react-native, callback, native

After user click login button, I'd like to do 3 steps in following order
1) sign up user on server
2) log user to server 
3) open a home page

this.props.login and this.props.signUp is async function, coming from action. 
What the correct way to make them work one after another in particular order?
Should I use callbacks or some life-circle method?

Please give an example how to make it work.

Thanks!

```js
...
import { login, signUp} from 'action';

class Auth extends Component {

    handleLogin(){
      const { name, email, password} = this.props; 
      this.props.signUp( name, email, password)
      this.props.login(email,  password)
      this.props.navigtion.navigate('Home')
    }
  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <Button 
          title='Login'
          onPress={()=> this.handleLogin()}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use async await in handleLogin(). This way the login() will be called only after the signUp() promise resolves.

```
async handleLogin(){
      const { name, email, password} = this.props; 
      await this.props.signUp(name, email, password)
      await this.props.login(email,  password)
      this.props.navigtion.navigate('Home')
    }
```

Another way would be to put the login() inside the `.then` of signUp(). This will work same as the async await. The login() will be called after the signUp() resolves. You can then put the navigate() inside the `.then` of login() if you want to navigate only after the user is logged in.

```
handleLogin(){
      const { name, email, password} = this.props; 
      this.props.signUp(name, email, password)
      .then(this.props.login(email,  password)
      .then(this.props.navigtion.navigate('Home'))
      )
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

this is how I did it and it all work, but i'm not sure if it's okay in terms of best practice and clear syntax.

When the user click button, it's run _handleSignup() 
after checking all inputs it's run async function step by step.

```js
  async _handleSignup() {
    const { name, email, password, passwordConfirm, phone } = this.props;
    if (name.length === 0 && email.length === 0) {
      Alert.alert('Make sure all inputs is filled');
      return;
    } else if (password !== passwordConfirm) {
      Alert.alert('Password not match');
      return;
    }
      await this.props.signUp(name, email, password)
      await this.props.login(email, password).then(
        Alert.alert('Account created', [
          {
            text:'Login',
            onPress: ()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('Category')
          }
        ])
      )
  }
```